# Can I add different tax and banking information for different iOS apps?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, iphone-developer-program

If I have two iOS apps with in-app purchases. How can I add different "agreement, tax and banking" information for each one of them? or do I need to have two different Apple developer accounts?

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not using the same developer account. To do this you would need to create a separate developer account.

Comment: By separate developer account you mean adding a new user to my apple's account and then try to add my banking and tax info from it, or should I create a whole new developer account and pay the 99$ again?